# Dealer Financing Fell Through on vehicle purchase: Scam?

Tags: scams

I purchased a 2011 Dodge van 2 weeks ago, and traded in my Expedition for it.

Of course, the Dealership didn't want to give me the full amount of the value of the new car in exchange for the trade-in.

**Long story short, I found out the van was never approved to be financed.**

I need to know if the dealership is scamming me for trading my vehicle in for the Dodge van I'd agreed to purchase, that was never financed.

**Is this legal?**

Comment: This is confusing to read. Did the dealership let you drive away with a van when financing hadn't been approved? What trade in are you talking about?  Questions about legality should be posted on law.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Please add puntuation, and break this into sentences.

Comment: You should always arrange for you own finanicing.  You will get a better deal and it makes a complicated negotiation process far more simple.  You can still do this, get the van financed by your bank or credit union and present the dealer with a check for the purchase price.

Comment: A question like this would probably make more sense under the law stack exchange, where the community could cite specific statutes, laws, and legal remedies that are available, but they'd likely depend on area. You need a lawyer

Answer (score 3):

There's a good explanation of this type of scam at the following link; It's known as a Spot-Delivery scam.

https://www.carbuyingtips.com/top-10-scams/scam1.htm

Also, I read this one a while back, and immediately this post reminded me of it:
http://oppositelock.kinja.com/when-the-dealership-steals-back-the-car-they-just-sold-1636730607

Essentially, they claim you'll get one level of financing, let you take the car home, and then attempt to extort a higher financing APR out of you or request more money / higher payments.

Check your purchasing agreement, it may have a note with something along the lines of 'Subject to financing approval' or something similar. If it does, you might be 'out of luck', as it were.

Contact an attorney; in some cases (Such as the 'oppositelock.kinja.com' article above) consumers have been able to sue dealers for this as theft.